# jQuery -- stop animation within plugin using public methods of that plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-animate

I'm using the [extended jQuery Plugin Boilerplate](https://github.com/zenorocha/jquery-boilerplate/wiki/Extending-jQuery-Boilerplate) to write a plugin that has public methods to start/stop an animation running within the plugin; this animation is not a CSS amin BTW, it's just a counter so I can fire another method with the function on each `step`.

The animation starts from within the `init()` method:

```
Plugin.prototype = {
    init: function () {
        // Place initialization logic here
        // You already have access to the DOM element and
        // the options via the instance, e.g. this.element
        // and this.options
        // you can add more functions like the one below and
        // call them like so: this.yourOtherFunction(this.element, this.options).
        console.log('init');

        $({ i: 0 }).animate({ i: 1000 }, {
            duration: 1000
        ,   step:     function () { console.log(this.i); }
        });
    },
    stop: function () { //yourOtherFunction: function () {
        // some logic
        console.log('stop');

        $(this.element).clearQueue();
        $(this.element).stop();
    }
};
```

And does start just fine, when called like `$('.some-elements').wheels();`.

I would like a way to pause or stop this animation by calling a public function, for example:

```
var timeout = window.setTimeout(function () {
    $('#total.cont-email-wheel').wheels('stop');
}, 500);
```

This example would stop the animation around half way through (I understand the inaccuracies of timeouts etc.), but it doesn't; which is why I'm here!

*NB: `stop` is logged to the console around the halfway mark, so the method is being called properly.*

I'm pretty sure, by looking at the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/) that I need to be calling `clearQueue()` and `stop()` on the object being animated, which in this case is an anonymous object (`{ i }`), not the element(s) but I've no clue how to do this.

Any help would be much appreciated; I've tried to explain as concisely as possible but if it's not clear I'll try to clarify in the comments!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem I was correct to assume I needed to call the `clearQueue` and `stop` methods on the object being animated so I extended `this.element` with the property `i` so I could animate that instead of the anonymous object.

This means I can now call `clearQueue` and `stop` methods to pause the animation on the `this.element` object, which can be accessed from any method within the plugin.

```
Plugin.prototype = {
    init: function () {
        // Place initialization logic here
        // You already have access to the DOM element and
        // the options via the instance, e.g. this.element
        // and this.options
        // you can add more functions like the one below and
        // call them like so: this.yourOtherFunction(this.element, this.options).
        console.log('init');

        $.extend(this.element, { i: 0 });

        $(this.element).animate({ i: 1000 }, {
            duration: 1000
        ,   step:     function () { console.log(this.i); }
        });
    },
    stop: function () { //yourOtherFunction: function () {
        // some logic
        console.log('stop');
        console.log($(this.element));

        $(this.element).clearQueue();
        $(this.element).stop();
    }
};
```

By doing this, I now don't need my own public methods to stop the animation as jQuery's native `stop()` method will work just fine. Also, If I want to pause/resume the animation I could now use the plethora of pause/resume plugins already available. No need to re-write the wheel!